# PySpark on Windows with PyCharm: java.net.SocketException

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, socketexception

Since yesterday I am facing a weird behavior with my pySpark code. I am working on windows with PyCharm and Spark 1.5.

I run successfully the following code on an ipython notebook (with the same version of python but on a cluster). However while launching it on my Windows environment with Pycharm I got this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

# SQL / Spark context:
conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("analysis"))#.set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Input CSV files :
inputCsvFile = "survey.csv"
separator = ','

# read the input file into a RDD
rdd = sc.textFile(inputCsvFile).split(separator)
header = rdd.first().split(separator)

# build the Schema: (some basic functions to chreate StructType object with string as default type)
schema = dictSchemaFromColumnsList(header)
schemaDf = dictSchemaToDFSchema(schema)

# create Dataframe:
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schemaDf)
pprint(rdd.first())
print('\ndf.count()=' + str(df.count()))

# display
df.show()
```

> 16/06/23 11:46:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0
>   (TID 1)
>
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)   at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
>     at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)    at
>   java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:590)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:410)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
>   16/06/23 11:46:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID
>   1, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer:
>   socket write error    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)   at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
>     at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)    at
>   java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:590)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:410)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
>
> 16/06/23 11:46:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1
>   times; aborting job 16/06/23 11:46:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed
>   TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool  16/06/23
>   11:46:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1 16/06/23 11:46:32
>   INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:361)
>   failed in 0.792 s 16/06/23 11:46:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed:
>   runJob at PythonRDD.scala:361, took 0.802922 s Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/pySpark_analysis/Survey_2011-2016_Analysis.py",
>   line 38, in 
>       df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schemaDf)   File "C:\Spark\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\context.py",
>   line 404, in createDataFrame
>       rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)   File
>   "C:\Spark\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\context.py",
>   line 296, in _createFromRDD
>       rows = rdd.take(10)   File "C:\Spark\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1299,
>   in take
>       res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)   File "C:\Spark\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\context.py", line
>   916, in runJob
>       port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)   File
>   "C:\Spark\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py",
>   line 538, in **call**   File
>   "C:\Spark\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line
>   36, in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)   File "C:\Spark\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection
>   reset by peer: socket write error     at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)   at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
>     at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)    at
>   java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:590)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:410)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1280)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1268)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1813)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1826)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1839)     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:361)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)   at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
>     at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)    at
>   java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:590)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:410)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
>
> 16/06/23 11:46:32 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown
>   hook

Strangely, if I run the code in debug mode and add a basic instruction like:

```
People=["1,Maj,123","2,Pvt,333","3,Col,999"]
rrd1=sc.parallelize(People)
rrd1.first()
```

I get sometime the code to work.... which makes the run not consistent....
Any suggestion would be appreciated...

UPDATE:
After looking back to the problem it looks to be exactly the same behavior Matei described hereafter. Apparently the problem gets solved while shorting the input csv file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using (let's say) big files (20000 lines) and trying to filter them using a regex:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("...")
rdd.filter(lambda x: pattern.search(x) is not None)
```

Also the behavior was intermittent as you describe. 
After truncating the file to ~ 2000 lines, it worked without errors.